# Problema al incluir autoload.php de la librería VIMEO

Tags: php

Es que trato de obtener una lista de los videos de un usuario en específico, pero no puedo proceder porque me lanza el siguiente error:

> ```
>  Warning: require_once(/storage/ssd1/102/066102/public_html/vimeo/autoload.php):
>  failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>  /storage/ssd1/102/9066102/public_html/prueba/index.php on line 16
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
> '/storage/ssd1/102/9066102/public_html/vimeo/autoload.php'
> (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in
> /storage/ssd1/102/9066102/public_html/prueba/index.php on line 16
> ```

[image: Imagen muestra de mi error]

Ya he utilizado 4 diferentes formas de incluir este archivo, usé:

```
//primer metodo
require once __DIR__ . '/vimeo/autoload.php';
//segundo metodo
require once("/vimeo/autoload.php")
tercer metodo
require once("vimeo/autoload.php")
//cuarto metodo
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/vimeo/autoload.php';
```

Actualmente todos lo archivos se encuentran en 000webhost, todos incluidos en la carpeta public_html.

**¿Cómo instalé la librería en mi servidor?**

- Descargué la librería Vimeo desde [gitHub](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php#upload-videos-from-the-server)
- Creé un nuevo directorio en mi servidor con el nombre de vimeo
- Cargué todos los archivos de la librería descargada en ese directorio

[image: vista]

Ya no encuentro otro método qué probar. Gracias y espero su pronta ayuda.

Comment: El problema es que el archivo `autoload.php` no está en ninguna de esas ubicaciones. ¿Cómo instalaste la librería? Tienes que verificar tus carpetas para determinar dónde se encuentra ese archivo realmente.

Comment: Amigo no se si mi procedimiento es el correcto, pero hice lo siguiente la librería descargue la librería de vimeo desde gitHub y cree en servidor una carpeta, la cual llame carpeta vimeo y en esta en esta cargue todos los archivos de la api de vimeo que obtuve de gitHub, el archivo autoload.php si existe, ya voy actualizar mi pregunta para subir un capture.

Comment: Tienes un comentario sin los `//`

Comment: Disculpa no entiendo, en donde no coloque el **//**.

Comment: ¿Si accedes directamente desde el navegador a autoload.php te da error?

Comment: No accedo directamente desde el navegador, utilizo una función de 00webhost que me permite visualizar y cargar mi web en el servidor y navegador.

Comment: Los mensajes de error son clarísimos: ***`failed to open stream: No such file or directory in `*** la traducción literal es ***`El fichero o directorio no existe ...`***. Instalar y hacer funcionar librerías *a mano* según mi experiencia es un calvario, aparte de que mantenerlas actualizadas es penoso. ¿Por qué no instalas la librería vía `composer` o mediante `git`. ?

Comment: **Otra cosa que se ve en la imagen**, es que dentro de `public_html` **hay una carpeta `prueba`** y luego dentro de esa carpeta es donde se encuentra la carpeta de `vimeo`. La carpeta `prueba` no aparece en ninguna de las posibilidades que has intentado. Inclúyela a ver que pasa. Y si no funciona de ninguna de las maneras, intenta con una ruta absoluta: `https://files.000webhost.com/prueba/vimeo/autoload.php` o usando la ruta interna que te muestra el mensaje de error: `/storage/ssd1/102/9066102/public_html/`  ... lo cierto es que falta la carpeta `prueba` en tu ruta.

Comment: Voy ha intentar con lo que comento (A. Cedano), ademas sino, funciona lo voy a probar con composer ya estoy descargando un complemente que le falta a mi windows. Gracias ya les comento mi progreso.

Comment: Gracias el error fue que no importe correctamente la librería en el servidor, ya que me faltaban ciertos archivos y directorios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El mensaje de error es inequívoco en este caso:

> ... No such file or directory in ...

lo cual significa:

> ... archivo o directorio no encontrado

En la [imagen de tu estructura de archivos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7LT1.png) vemos algo así:

```
├── public_html
│   ├── prueba
│   │   ├── vimeo
│   |       ├── autoload.php
```

Por lo que la ruta donde estaría el archivo sería: `prueba/vimeo/autoload.php`, pero en tus `require` el directorio `prueba` no es usado, por lo tanto nunca lo encontrarás.

### Instalar librerías

Instalar librerías de forma manual, copiando las carpetas directamente, no es evidente. Resulta tedioso, a veces algunos archivos no se copian y actualizar la librería a nuevas versiones es un dolor de cabeza.

Por eso generalmente las librerías indican en la misma documentación instrucciones para ser instaladas mediante gestores de paquete. En PHP lo más usado es `composer`. De hecho, la librería que nos ocupa [indica la forma de instalarla vía Composer](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php#installation):

> Require this package, with Composer, in the root directory of your
>   project.
>
> ```
>     composer require vimeo/vimeo-api
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Requerir este paquete, con Composer, en el directorio raíz de su proyecto.
>
> ```
>     composer require vimeo/vimeo-api
> ```

Haciendo esto, todos los archivos de la librería se copian en el directorio raíz del proyecto.

A veces (muy raras) Composer no está instalado en el servidor. En ese caso se puede instalar dicho paquete.

Si es imposible instalar Composer, también se pueden copiar los archivos mediante comando `git`.

Por ejemplo este comando copiaría todos los archivos de la librería en el directorio `public_html`:

```
git clone https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php.git public_html
```

Para ello el módulo `git` debe estar instalado en el servidor.

### Nota final

Siempre es recomendable dar preferencia a `composer`.

Para verificar si esos módulos está instalados en el servidor puedes ejecutar esto en línea de comandos:

- `composer version`
- `git version`

Para instalarlos, tendrías que revisar la documentación según el entorno PHP que tengas.

Answer (score 0):

El error fue causado por una errónea importación de la librería en el servidor ya que me faltaban algunos archivos y directorios claves para su funcionamiento. Volví a descargar las librería y subirla manual nuevamente y la incluí en mi script con método simple y funciono.

**Método con el cual incluí la librería**

```
require_once ('vimeo/autoload.php');
```

ademas tambien la saque del directorio `prueba` y la coloque directamente en el directorio `public_html`

**Así debe estar la librería**
[image: vista]